# Resolver cálculos con reduce - Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, calculo, reduce

El problema que estoy intentando resolver tiene como objetivo realizar el siguiente cálculo tomando como base un **arreglo de objetos** que puede variar según las necesidades.

Por ejemplo:

```
[
  {
    capital: 576.5599975585938,
    diferenciaDias: 1510,
    interes: 0.509,
    porcentajeTotal: 100,
    porcentajeNoAsignado: 0.121,
    estado: 'NOASIGNADO'
  },
  {
    capital: 576.5599975585938,
    diferenciaDias: 1482,
    interes: 0.197,
    porcentajeTotal: 100,
    porcentajeNoAsignado: 0.121,
    estado: 'NOASIGNADO'  
  },
  {
    capital: 576.5599975585938,
    diferenciaDias: 964,
    interes: 0.141667,
    porcentajeTotal: 100,
    porcentajeNoAsignado: 0.121,
    estado: 'NOASIGNADO'
  },
  {
    capital: 576.5599975585938,
    diferenciaDias: 902,
    interes: 0.1,
    porcentajeTotal: 100,
    porcentajeNoAsignado: 0.121,
    estado: 'NOASIGNADO'
  }
]
```

El problema:

1. Tomar el primer elemento de la matriz y obtener el valor de diferenciaDias (1510).
2. Restárselo al segundo elemento (diferenciaDias 1482). El resultado multiplicarlo por interés y capital del primer elemento.
3. Obtenida esa multiplicación, dividirla por el porcentajeTotal, también del primer elemento.
4. En caso de que estado figure como NOASIGNADO, al total del punto anterior, multplicarlo por la propiedad porcentajeNoAsignado del primer elemento.
5. Repetir esta acción para los siguientes elementos. Es decir, luego de resolver lo anterior, tomar el segundo elemento y aplicar la lógica mencionada con el tercer elemento. Y así sucesivamente, las N cantidad de elementos que se encuentren.
6. Hacer la suma de todos los resultados obtenidos y sumárselo al capital. Si se calculó porcentajeNoAsignado a los casos NOASIGNADO, también agregarle ese resultado al capital.
7. Devolver un objeto señalando: interés calculado, porcentajeNoAsignado en los casos correspondientes y total (la suma del interés calculado y procentajeNoAsignado).

El cálculo:

- (1510 - 1482) * 0.509 * 576.55 / 100 = 82.17
- (1482 - 964) * 0.197 * 576.55 / 100 = 588.35
- (964 - 902) * 0.141667 * 576.55 / 100 = 50.64
- 902 * 0.1 * 576.55 / 100 = 520.05

{ **interesCalculado**: 1241.23
**porcentajeNoAsignado**: 219.95
**total**: 2037.74 }

- interesCalculado: 82.17 + 588.35 + 50.64 + 520.05
- porcentajeNoAsignado: (576.55 + 1241.23) * 0.121
- total: 576.55 + 1241.23 + 219.95

Nota: si estado hubiera sido asignado, porcentajeNoAsignado huberia sido cero y el resultado para total sería de 1817.79

Yo intenté aplicando **reduce** pero los resultados no eran para nada similares y no estoy entendiendo cómo resolverlo más allá de comprender el objetivo en cuestión.

```
if (intereses.length > 1) {
  intereses.reduce((acc: any, crr: any, index: number, array: []) => {
    console.log("acc -->", acc, "crr -->", crr); // acc --> undefined, crr --> { capital: 576.5...., etc... }
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: y cual fue el reduce que probastE?? porque sin verlo, dificil decirte que hiciste mal... de paso.. porque reduce??? no podias hacerlo con un for exactamente como lo pedian?

Comment: Estoy terminando de modificar el reduce que quiero implementar (aunque no llegue a los resultados esperados) y modifico el post; no es problema utilizar un bucle for.

Comment: El punto 4 donde se ve reflejado?

Comment: A mi no me da el resultado que mostras, solamente el interesCalculado me da tal cual y solo si son todos "NOASIGNADO". No se si estoy entendiendo mal o que. Estoy intentando seguir el algoritmo que mostras.

Comment: El total tampoco entiendo de como sale

Comment: En el caso de NOASIGNADO, el resultado es 219, 95

Comment: Toda la informacion que ayude a esclarecer la pregunta agregala a la propia pregunta, editandola.

Comment: El total es la suma de interés calculado (1241.23) + porcentajeNoAsignado (219.95) + capital (576.55). Ahora lo aclaro nuevamente en la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: ok, ya voy entendiendo. Aun queda por resolver la inconsistencia del punto (4), por que en tus cálculos no se ve reflejado eso que dices ahí

Comment: Y por último recuerda que debes ingresar a tu pregunta un intento sincero de resolver el problema, así nos evitamos todos malos ratos

Comment: es tan pero tan facil hacer esto con un for yendo para atras, que no entiendo que tratan de hacer...

Comment: podría ser un for + reverse() entonces para no ir hacia atrás; ahora pruebo...

Comment: Vuelvo a insistirte en el punto (4), a mi el porcentajeNoAsignado me da 150.18, según tu algoritmo este se debe calcular en cada iteración (el punto 5 dice que se repite el calculo del 1 al 4), pero en tus cálculos haces simplemente `(capital + interesCalculado) * porcentajeNoAsignado` Y supongo yo que esos valores corresponden al primer item, pero es que cada item tiene sus propias propiedades `capital ` y  `porcentajeNoAsignado`

Comment: Es que el 0.121 que se multiplica por la suma total entre capital e interesCalculado, se aplica cuando estado contiene el valor NOASIGNADO. Entonces, con un IF simplemente se chequea que si estado cumple esa condición, se realiza por única vez esa multiplicación.

Comment: y el codigo??? donde esta??? reverse()????? pero si simplemente es recorrer el array del ultimo al segundo... porque complicar tanto un algoritmo de calculo tan simple????

Comment: gbianchi, admiro la soberbia con la que señalas tus comentarios, ahí dejo actualizado como lo estoy resolviendo con un bucle for. El reverse() es invertir ese array de ejemplo nada más.

Comment: Me gustaría ayudar. Pero no es clara la intención que quiere lograr. 
Por lo que veo es un algoritmo que no se puede resolver con una sola función de un objeto de tipo Array. Tampoco hay una solución en código para analizar y probar

Answer (score 0):

Al final he optado por utilizar el **bucle for** para hacer la resta entre el elemento actual donde se encuentre posicionado y el elemento anterior. Para que se entienda mejor, dejo un fragmento del código que estoy implementando:

```
let interesCalculado = 0;
 
for (let interes = 0; interes < intereses.length; interes++) {
 const interesAnterior = intereses[interes - 1] ? intereses[interes -1].diferenciaDias : 0;
 const interesActual = intereses[interes].diferenciaDias;
 const diferenciaDias = interesActual - interesAnterior;
 interesCalculado += (diferenciaDias * intereses[interes].capital * intereses[interes].interes) / intereses[interes].porcentajeTotal;
}
```

De esta forma estoy obteniendo los resultados esperados. Solo me queda por aplicar la estructura de control que valide los casos "NOASIGNADO" para aplicarle el 0.121